# What is the syntax in importlib to import sub-submodules locally?

Tags: python

I am trying to import a library, normally it will be like this:

```
import tti
from tti.indicators import AccumulationDistributionLine
```

now I have download the library and I am trying to import it locally, it is in a separate folder than my project under the same parent folder git:

```
git
    tti
    myProject
```

This is what I have tried

```
import importlib  
local_tti = importlib.import_module("./../tti", package="tti", package="indicators")
from local_tti.indicators import AccumulationDistributionLine
```

I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'indicators'
```

I am using python 3

Comment: `sys.path.append` may help you.